# Redirect using wildcards in Joomla

Tags: php, redirect, joomla

I'm on joomla and there is a redirect component in joomla where in i can just enter the source and the destination urls. What I want to achieve is this

www.mysite.com/index.php/community/profile/1005

should be redirected to

www.mysite.com/index.php/connect/profile/1005

The problem here is that the number "1005" is a variable and keeps changing with profile. I tried
Source:  www.mysite.com/index.php/connect/profile/(.*)
Destination: www.mysite.com/index.php/connect/profile/$1

but it isn't working. Any help will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: You might want to check at http://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want to do is a regular expression that changes all your urls starting for "www.mysite.com/index.php/community/profile/". It's not really difficult, you should add it to your htaccess. Check this guide: http://www.webforgers.net/mod-rewrite/mod-rewrite-syntax.php

Comment: This is a good question but I've spent days trying to add redirects to the .htaccess file provided by Joomla and it is really difficult to do. Saying that adding a redirect to your htaccess is "not really difficult" is not an answer.